# Filtering Asana tasks by multiple tags

Tags: php, asana

Once more the task bestowed on me is to work with the Asana API. What I am trying to do is to generate certain filtered lists with tasks.

What I am trying to get out of the API:

```
- A list of all tasks for all users and in all projects and workspaces
- A list of tasks with all tasks having certain tags (filtered by more than one tag)
```

With filtering on tags I mean: Get all tasks that have tag `A`, tag `B` and tag `E`.

Is this possible with the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently neither is possible - fetching a list of tasks requires either a project, tag, or assignee, and you can only fetch the tasks for a specific tag. We've thought about how to support more advanced queries, but we don't yet have that on our roadmap.

Comment: I have the tags `pending` and `week08`. Is there no way for me to filter my tasks on these two tags?